# なにかあったら呼んでくれ、と言いたい所だが、悪いが呼ばれても何もできん

Tags: translation

> なにかあったら呼んでくれ、と言いたい所だが、悪いが呼ばれても何もできん

And my attempt to translate:

> I want to say, call me if something happens, but I can't do anything if you call me wrong.

I think I got something wrong, but I don't know what...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「なにかあったら呼{よ}んでくれ、と言{い}いたい所{ところ}だが、悪{わる}いが呼ばれても何{なに}もできん。」

And your attempt to translate is:

> "I want to say, call me if something happens, but I can't do anything if you **call me wrong**".

My question would be "Where are you getting 'call me wrong' from?"

「悪いが」 in that sentence means "***I'm sorry, but***", "***unfortunately***", etc.

「呼ばれても」 is in the passive voice, meaning "***if I am called (by you)***".
Note that I used the active voice "if you called me" instead for a more natural-sounding translation.

So, the sentence means:

> "I'd like to ask/tell you to call me if something happens, but I'm sorry I wouldn't be able to do anything if you called me."

Comment: There so much translations in dictionary for 悪い, that I got lost... And  I thought が after 悪い was subject marker, and tried to choose meaningful translation of 悪い, so...